# Writing excel cell data to datagridview cells (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net, excel, loops, datagridview

I loop through the columns and within the columns loop I loop through the rows. The way I have my excel file laid out is the columns are each date and the rows include the individual data for various values. The problem is the dataviewgrid isn't being populated with the values from my excel file. Here's my loop

```
' Get the Excel application object.
    excel_app = New Excel.Application

    ' Make Excel visible (optional).
    excel_app.Visible = False

    ' Open the workbook.
    workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Michael Jr\Desktop\iBudgetBuddy\Records.xlsx", , True)
    sheet_name = "Sheet1"

    sheet = excel_app.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ColumnCount, RowCount As Long
    ColumnCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    RowCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = ColumnCount
    DataGridView1.RowCount = RowCount
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False

    **For ecIndex As Integer = 0 To ColumnCount
        Dim drIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim dcolumnIndex As Integer = 0
        For erIndex As Integer = 0 To RowCount
            DataGridView1.Rows(drIndex).Cells(dcolumnIndex).Value = sheet.Cells(erIndex, ecIndex).Value
            erIndex = erIndex + 1
            drIndex = drIndex + 1
        Next
        dcolumnIndex = dcolumnIndex + 1
        ecIndex = ecIndex + 1
    Next**

End Sub
```

Any idea why it's not working?

****Edit****
I've been able to successfully get the program to read and create the rows and columns. It populates the first column, which is the headings (examples income, expenses) of what the row contains. However, it does not populate anything in the 2nd column on. Why would it do that? My edited loop looks like this

```
    For cIndex As Integer = 0 To ColumnCount

        For rIndex As Integer = 0 To RowCount
            DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex, cIndex).Value()
        Next

    Next
```

Comment: As you are using XLSX I recommend you should drop interop use something like CloseXML to read your your exel files. 
Any error showing or just nothing happening?

Comment: You can use OleDB to open the excel file and populate your dataset and then use that to populate the DGV?

Comment: My guess is that you have this code wrapped in a try...catch that simply consumes errors, and it's bombing out when you try to reference `sheet.Cells(0,0)` the first time through your loops. Excel.Interop uses 1-based indexing for cells.

Comment: No errors, just nothing happening. I've attempted to use OleDB, but I've run into too many problems with errors saying I don't have any version I've tried (I'm a x64 windows 7 and I'm assuming x32 office). I've attempted many solutions for the OleDB problem found on the internet, but to no avail so I've pretty much given up on that. Would you have any suggestions or maybe some code that I could plug in possibly?